# Is it possible to use an Idea 9 Android module in a Teamcity IPR runner?

Tags: android, teamcity, teamcity-5.1

As per my question here...

http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5261667#5261667

Is it possible to use TeamCity with an Idea 9 project project that has 3 .iml modules where 2 are Java based and 1 in an Android module?

Answer (score 0):

According to the log posted in the forum there is no .idea directory under /trunk/guru in your repository, therefore TeamCity is not able to load the project after performing checkout.